# How to get all characters in a Culture?

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I am developing on .NET 4.5, US English. I need to capture "normal printable" characters from Culture 1041 (Japanese) used for human readable communication into a string in code. If I as just building a us-eng string, my result would be everything in the ASCII table from 32 to 127. I don't know the equivalent of hat for culture code 1041...

All ideas appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The Culture has no concept of "normal printable" characters I think. What you probably want is the codepage Windows would use for that culture and then somehow figure out to what unicode characters the entries of the codepage map to, but I don't know of any good API to work with codepages in C#